# Accessibility Service for Detectug Popup Menu Item click

Tags: android, popupmenu, accessibilityservice

I am using Android 's Accessibility Service to detect event when user clicks on "share" option in Popup Menu or Context Menu

Using TYPE_VIEW_CLICK i can only get the clicking event on views like Button,TextView,LinerLayout, etc.

Using TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED i can only detect that a pop-up menu has been created but i can't find out which option of pop-up menu was clicked

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same, I cannot achieve it.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not yet

Comment: I am also trying to detect a tap on a popup context menu but can't seem to do so. I've also tried TYPE_VIEW_CONTEXT_CLICKED but that does not fire either. Has anyone found a way?